# Invalide charater error associated with "Select-Case" vba

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, vba, error-999999

Anyone see a problem with the following code.  I keep getting a 999999 - invalid character error.

```
Select Case [code]
  case 5112: x = "AP030"   ' trunk<br /> 
  case 5113: x = "AP030"   ' primary<br /> 
  case 5113: x = "AP030"   ' primary<br /> 
  case 5114: x = "AP030"   ' secondary<br /> 
  case 5115: x = "AP030"   ' tertiary<br /> 
  case 5121: x = "AP030"   ' unclassified<br /> 
  case 5122: x = "AP030"   ' residential<br /> 
  case 5123: x = "AP050"   ' living_street<br /> 
  case 5124: x = "AP050"   ' pedestrian<br /> 
  case 5131: x = "AP030"   ' motoway_link<br /> 
  case 5132: x = "AP030"   ' trunk_link<br /> 
  case 5133: x = "AP030"   ' primary_link<br /> 
  case 5134: x = "AP030"   ' secondary_link<br /> 
  case 5135: x = "AP030"   ' tertiary_link<br /> 
  case 5141: x = "AP030"   ' service<br /> 
  case 5142: x = "AP050"   ' track<br /> 
  case 5143: x = "AP010"   ' track_grade1<br /> 
  case 5144: x = "AP010"   ' track_grade2<br /> 
  case 5145: x = "AP010"   ' track_grade3<br /> 
  case 5146: x = "AP010"   ' track_grade4<br /> 
  case 5147: x = "AP010"   ' track_grades5<br /> 
  case 5151: x = "AP050"   ' bridleway<br /> 
  case 5152: x = "AP050"   ' cycleway<br /> 
  case 5153: x = "AP050"   ' footpath<br /> 
  case 5154: x = "AP050"   ' path<br /> 
  case 5155: x = "AQ150"   ' steps<br /> 
  case 5199: x = "AP050"   ' unkknown<br /> 
end select
```

[image: Field Calculator]

Comment: shouldn't it be `Select Case code`

Comment: No ... "code" needs to be in brackets [code], in vba.  That much I'm pretty sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code, output:

[image]

Nothing wrong with it.

Just retype first line, or insert empty line after it. Some sort of a hidden character I guess:

```
Select Case [code]
  case 5112: x = "AP030"   ' trunk<br /> 
  case 5113: x = "AP030"   ' primary<br /> 
  case 5113: x = "AP030"   ' primary<br /> 
  case 5114: x = "AP030"   ' secondary<br /> 
  case 5115: x = "AP030"   ' tertiary<br /> 
  case 5121: x = "AP030"   ' unclassified<br /> 
  case 5122: x = "AP030"   ' residential<br /> 
  case 5123: x = "AP050"   ' living_street<br /> 
  case 5124: x = "AP050"   ' pedestrian<br /> 
  case 5131: x = "AP030"   ' motoway_link<br /> 
  case 5132: x = "AP030"   ' trunk_link<br /> 
  case 5133: x = "AP030"   ' primary_link<br /> 
  case 5134: x = "AP030"   ' secondary_link<br /> 
  case 5135: x = "AP030"   ' tertiary_link<br /> 
  case 5141: x = "AP030"   ' service<br /> 
  case 5142: x = "AP050"   ' track<br /> 
  case 5143: x = "AP010"   ' track_grade1<br /> 
  case 5144: x = "AP010"   ' track_grade2<br /> 
  case 5145: x = "AP010"   ' track_grade3<br /> 
  case 5146: x = "AP010"   ' track_grade4<br /> 
  case 5147: x = "AP010"   ' track_grades5<br /> 
  case 5151: x = "AP050"   ' bridleway<br /> 
  case 5152: x = "AP050"   ' cycleway<br /> 
  case 5153: x = "AP050"   ' footpath<br /> 
  case 5154: x = "AP050"   ' path<br /> 
  case 5155: x = "AQ150"   ' steps<br /> 
  case 5199: x = "AP050"   ' unkknown<br /> 
end select
```

Comment: Well it looks as though you may have something.  I retyped the first couple of lines and it ran fine - odd??  Good suggestion.